# How to serialize / deserialize coffeescript objects to / from strings?

Tags: javascript, serialization, coffeescript, local-storage, deserialization

I have instances of coffeescript classes that I need to save to and load from local storage (which only accepts strings).  Is there a best practice way to serialize / de-serialize CS objects?  Do I just create new instances and jam the data back in?

Simply using JSON.stringify isn't enough because there are functions on the objects that won't be saved.

Comment: Trying to serialize functions generally doesn't work out so well. Are you creating these new functions at run-time or is there some other reason that you can't leave the functions on classes where they (usually) belong?

Comment: The functions are on classes, but JSON stringify / parse sets the prototype of everything back to Object.

Comment: Could you override `toJSON` and insert a `_type` property which contains the class name?